# List/Record of Online Photos Used - John's Background Switcher

Tags: desktop-customization

Regarding the program John's Background Switcher, where can I find links to or a record of all the pictures automatically selected and then used as the desktop background, such as those taken from Flickr?

My goal is to find the original links of past pictures chosen by the program, because I've set the program to rotate to a new background every hour and want to keep this frequency.

I tried Cached Picture Browser but see nothing.

John's Background Switcher had been supernally suggested and tendered by user Rik [here](https://superuser.com/a/679713/269574) (a post which I wish were undeleted, at least, because the answers volunteered for this question are inestimable and efficacious and would verily help many others).

Comment: Used in where? Could you explain a little more on what you want to do?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I've just emended my post. Better?

Comment: Slightly... I still didn't understood what you wanted, so I tried the program. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to log where  *every* picture that is displayed by the program came from? If so, I'm afraid that the program doesn't have that feature (as far as I'm concerned, it can store every file under memory). Maybe a 3rd party solution can help. I would look into network loggers. Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/a/417067/228536) answer may help, in particular Fiddler (as for the introduction video it seemed to do what you wanted).

Comment: What makes you think this feature exists?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Yes; you are correct that I desire `to log where every picture that is displayed by the program came from`. If this feature does not exist, then your comment suffices. Thank you.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am just conjecturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late - but the absence of a reply here made me do a bit of detective work.

You can find the data in this location:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\johnsadventures.com\Background Switcher\
```

Each folder below seems to host a long list of chached images as well as an XML file with the origin of the images.