# My computer is using too much Internet bandwidth and having problems disabling BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service)

Tags: windows-7

My computer is using too much internet in background. I have a limited Internet plan and in few hours it consumes more than 600 MB. I have no idea which process are using Internet.

In the task manager and resource monitor nothing is showing and everything is normal but I am losing data from my limited Internet.

I think it is `svchost.exe` but I am not sure. I tried [BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799(v=vs.85).aspx) to disable it but it starts everytime I reboot. I have set the startup type of BITS to manual but it starts everytime.

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging individual application network usage in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/414073/logging-individual-application-network-usage-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools to see what applications are accessing the network, such as [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) and [Glasswire Free](https://www.glasswire.com/download/).

*svchost.exe* is the *Host Process for Windows Services*, and is used to run many different processes. Sysinternal's [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) gives more detail on what processes are hosted by *svchost* than does *Task Manager*.

You might also want to perform a full virus scan with one of the free tools availble, such as Avast!, Kaspersky AV and Malwarebytes; as it is possible that malware is causing the issue (e.g. being part of a botnet).

In addition to the analytic approach, which is best, you might try disabling any service that is *not* part of Windows or your antivirus; see [Black Viper’s Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/). *Caveat*: this could cause problems, so make at least a restore point, and preferably an image backup, before disabling questionable services.