# Monitoring data transfer on windows of android

Tags: windows-7, android

I connect my android phone with the laptop for internet on my laptop, I get 1 GB data transfer with 28 days validity whichever is earlier, my internet activity comprises of reading text on various websites, 1 GB is enough for me for 28 days.

Few days back I had to instal an app on my phone, so I enabled "Background data" under "Accounts and sync" settings, after installing the app I disabled it, but since then the data transfer is very high with my normal usage (visiting sites for reading) 750 MB in just 5 days , what can be the cause of such a high data transfer?

Is there any free app for android or windows 7 that will not only monitor the data transfer but also tell which application is doing it?

Comment: try netstat in dos. i t shows u connections your computer making

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to know how much data is used by your android phone without installing any app to your phone(This is true for Android JB, not sure about other versions).

- Fist, go to **Settings**.
- In **Wireless&Networks** section, tap on **Data Usage**.
- There, you can see your total data usage, if you swith to **Wi-Fi** or **Mobile** tab, you can see the apps used data and their individual usage.
  [image]
  [image]
  I hope this would clear the Android part. As for the Windows part, you could try a simple Google [Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=softwares+to+monitor+Windows+data+usage&sa=G&site=webhp&gbv=1&sei=_4C0Vc_hJo2hugTk0YLABg) to find some software for this purpose. There is a Superuser [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/414073/logging-individual-application-network-usage-in-windows-7) too for this purpose in windows.

***Note:***

- You may use third party apps to monitor data usage in android rather
  than my proposed way. In that case, you can find them by doing a
  google search.
- If I were you, I would check android apps first rather than windows as they are usually data hungry.

Comment: thanx, I have gingerbread, the pics you have posted are not applicable to gingerbread,  I will have to install an app or reset the phone to factory default settings.