# Logging individual application network usage in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, developer-tools

I'm writing a review on ACD (Amazon Cloud Drive), and I need to know the following data for the ACD process:

- Which addresses does it visit, IP and domain;
- How much data does it send;
- Bandwidth usage for each address and the process, especially the **average** upload/download speed;
- If the data is sent through TSL/SSL.

If there is an application that could provide this data in a chart, that's what I want.

I've read a similar question on [Logging individual application network usage in Windows 7 - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/414073/logging-individual-application-network-usage-in-windows-7), and tried five different tools: Fiddler2, Wireshark, NB (Net Balancer), MNM (Microsoft Network Monitor), MMA (Microsoft Message Analyzer). Fiddler2 and Wireshark it seems don't provide bandwidth average usage. NB doesn't provide the addresses that the ACD process visits. Even though I've tried to RTFM, I don't know how to use MNM or MMA to generate a chart that contains the data I want. ( ´_ゝ`)

Comment: I think [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) might have some of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'v used Glasswire for maybe a year. And it doesprovide function 1/2/4 I want. But it doesn't provide average bandwidth usage. It's important for a Cloud Drive.

Comment: How about [Networx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/)? It allows you to select a specific interface for monitoring, has averages and graphs, and allows you to track usage by application. Also, take a look at [Capsa](http://www.colasoft.com/capsa/).

Comment: I've tried Networx and it does provide usage by applications but not the specific application. But I've found that it provides a speed meter that allows me to log the bandwidth usage manually. Thanks for you help.