# Can I have a statistical log of app data usage in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, logging

I am using an ASUS laptop currently running windows 8. Recently while streaming a video on YouTube I found my data usage surge violently, over half an hour. Now I am on a wifi connection which is set as non-metered, but as my data pack is not unlimited(only one gb per day)  I want to have a look at which apps consume how much background data and identify them. Also let me know that is there any statistical representation of the same and any way to restrict the background data usage of individual apps(the feature which is available on android and is much handy).

Also note that by saying 'apps' I don't mean only windows store apps but any application or software on the computer(as the data usage history of windows store apps is present in the task manager).

I mean something of this sort only for all applications or software on my pc.

[image: Screenshot of the available feature on task manager]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging individual application network usage in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/414073/logging-individual-application-network-usage-in-windows-7)

Comment: I want the statistical data and with that I also want to disable or limit it's background data usage, so mine may be different. Moreover many tools that worked for Windows 7 do not work on Windows 8.( for example once I download an official Microsoft tool for Windows 7, I did not care about its compatibility, I thought it could also run on Windows 8 but when I tried to install it but it would not because it was not compatible, let me remember the tool name and I will let u know as soon as I remember)

Comment: taskmgr reads data from SRUM  database: C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat maybe you find a lib to which can read the data